# An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting the error

> "An item with the same key has already been added"

in production randomly.if i execute the below code in local i am not getting the issue.please suggestion needed to solve this issue.

```
//check for whether Midas.DAB is Enabled in the App.Config File
if (ProcessMidasDab)
{                    
    var dvFilteredMidasDabDetails = new DataView(dtMidasDabandSurgDetails) {
    RowFilter = "not (LastReceivedOnForDAB is null)" };

    dtCmMidasDabAlerts.Columns.Add("ClientID");
    dtCmMidasDabAlerts.Columns.Add("LastFileReceivedDate");
    dtCmMidasDabAlerts.Columns.Add("SendingSystem");    

    //Get the Cut-off time for Midas.DAB from the App.config.
    var timeStamp = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TimeLapseforMidasDABinhrs"];

    //Logic to check the Feed for Midas.DAB
    foreach (DataRowView dv in dvFilteredMidasDabDetails)
    {
        midasDabClientList.Add(Convert.ToInt32(dv["ClientID"]));
        var timeDifference =
            (DateTime.Now - Convert.ToDateTime(dv["LastReceivedOnForDAB"])).TotalHours;
        if (timeDifference > Convert.ToDouble(timeStamp))
        {
            var drNewRow = dtCmMidasDabAlerts.NewRow();
            drNewRow["ClientID"] = dv["ClientID"];
            drNewRow["LastFileReceivedDate"] = dv["LastReceivedOnForDAB"];
            drNewRow["SendingSystem"] = "Midas.DAB";
            dtCmMidasDabAlerts.Rows.Add(drNewRow);
        }
    }

    dabclients = midasDabClientList;
}
```

Comment: Is `dtCmMidasDabAlerts` static?

Comment: its not a static variable

Answer (score 0):

You have two time assign this

```
    drNewRow["Clientid"] = 12;
    drNewRow["ClientID"] = dv["ClientID"];
```

Please remove this one

```
drNewRow["Clientid"] = 12;
```

and also you have two time assigned this

```
dtCmMidasDabAlerts.Columns.Add("ClientID");
```

Comment: Even if this could be a bug it does not explain and prevent the exception. Also, where does OP add two times the column `ClientID`?

Comment: ramesh: even if we assign two values to a single rowid it will  take the last value.